# Grails interferes with jquery-tmpl syntax

Tags: jquery, grails, gsp, jquery-templates

The jQuery templates plug-in uses `${foo}` syntax ([example in jquery.tmpl doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/)):

```
$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", myData )
```

But Grails also uses it ([example in Grails doc](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.1.4%20Expressions)):

```
<body>
  Hello ${params.name}
</body>
```

So when I include `$.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", myData )` in my .gsp, Grails renders it as `$.tmpl( "<li></li>", myData );`.

Is there an easy way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the alt syntax:  {{= Name }}

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/

Comment: Nice. This is fewer characters than Nick's solution, and it doesn't hose my syntax highlighting either!

Answer (score 2):

I have only dabbled in Grails, but one option to get the literal output:

```
$.tmpl("<li><%='${Name}'%></li>", myData)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I had been trying crazy stuff like `${"\$\{Name\}"}` to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using jquery.noConflict or jQuery itself:

```
jQuery.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", myData )
```

or

```
var jqc = jQuery.noConflict();
jqc.tmpl( "<li>${Name}</li>", myData )
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid conflict , you should use the syntax mentioned by zack.
However,Be careful when you use this tag  :

```
{{= Name}}
```

you should have space between "=" and the first letter of variable.

<s>{{=Name}}</s>

{{= Name}}

EXAMPLE: 
  **WRONG**

```
<tr id="ad{{=idmatchingtem }}"></tr>
```

[image]

**RIGHT**

```
<tr id="ad{{= idmatchingtem }}"></tr>
```

[image]